# Graphics Magick output wrong colour when converting png to jpeg node js

Tags: node.js, heroku, ffmpeg, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Background is, I'm splitting a video (mp4, mov) into PNG frames using FFMPEG, then converting those to jpeg with GraphicsMagick.

So I'm using GraphicsMagick in NodeJS, from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) and below is a snippet:

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

gm('input.png')
.write('output.jpg', (err) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('done');
});
```

But the output jpeg colour is either washed out, or too dark.
See [here](http://s14.postimg.org/hngyv0ib5/compare.jpg) for the output. The original video is left (mov) and the converted JPEG's are middle and right.
The middle one, is the node app running on **Heroku** and the right image is the node app on **my osx machine**.

I've read it could be to do with 'profiles' but this doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
.profile('sRGB.icc')
```

'sRGB.icc' is a colour profile I've downloaded.

Any ideas?

I've also tried setting the colours amount to 16,777,216, tried setting the bit depth to 8 and 16, tried setting the colourspace to 'rgb' to no avail.

Comment: You're on the right track, most likely it's to do with profiles. You are best off looking at the PNGs properties (most image viewers have some way to find this) and seeing what colorspace that uses. Then you'll want to find the appropriate profile and use that to run your conversion.

Comment: Why do you not use `ffmpeg` to output to JPG?

Comment: I'm not outputting to JPEG from ffmpeg as I can't directly control the JPEG quality from there. Going to PNG first allows me to them specify the JPEG quality I want for the conversion in graphics magick.

Thanks, Benjamin, I'll have a look at that and see what I can find out.

Comment: @BenjaminKaiser
So the output PNG's have a colour space as `RGB` and a colour profile as `Calibrated RGB Colorspace`.
The output JPEG's don't have the profile, but I'm assuming my mac has a custom profile which what that calibrated one is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time and lots of testing and configuring (using Docker builds galore) the issue was that newer builds of FFMPEG render out images with some kind of messed up profile which causes the colour issue.

Reverting back to an older build of FFMPEG (2014 build) solved the issue.

Comment: Can you post the full console output of the movie to PNG command? I believe this is a matter of supplying the right format/swscaler flags.